# Preventing PHP from parsing escapes in a string

Tags: escaping, tex

I'm planning to store a bunch of user-submitted TeX equations in a database. Problem is, TeX has stuff like `\right`... and PHP likes to consider \r as a newline character.

Is there any way to suppress this behaviour? I've tried `addslashes` and `preg_replace`ing the `\r` with `\\r`, but neither have worked out.

Edit: An example of stuff I'm expecting to get:

```
\[\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{a_{11}}}&{{a_{12}}} \\ 
  {{a_{21}}}&{{a_{22}}} 
\end{array}} \right)\]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PHP likes to consider \r as a newline character.

Nope, PHP doesn't.
Just store these equations in a database usual way, there should be no problem.

You just need to follow 2 rules:

1. Let it be a really *user submitted* data, not hardcoded in your PHP file.
2. When put into SQL query, the data have to be properly formatted for this. Consult your database manual for the details.

Comment: Ok... trying I'm trying to print() the TeX chunk and getting `\[\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{a_{11}}}&{{a_{12}}} \ 
  {{a_{21}}}&{{a_{22}}} 
\end{array}} 
ight)\]` - The \r in \right is missing. I'm missing something here...

Comment: Piping it into json_encode and futzing around with preg_replace got it to work. Thanks for answering!